# Is "$ax+b$" group amenable?

Tags: topological-groups

Is the so-called "$ax+b$ group" (the group of affine maps on $\mathbb R$) [amenable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group)?

One reprersentation for $ax+b$ group is the set of 2 by 2 matrices for form 
$$\begin{bmatrix}x & y \\0 & 1\end{bmatrix};\,\,\,x,y\in\mathbb R, x>0$$ endowed with the usual multiplication. The left Haar measure is given by $\frac{dxdy}{x^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every solvable group is amenable - for a proof see Theorem $4.6.3$ [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=N-LSFFaHTKwC&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=is+the+affine+group+Aff(R%5En)+amenable?&source=bl&ots=j5zq9pZPgP&sig=czISnd57yRr9u1CXp_HreI9qMfU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXyuXRnK7RAhVEOhoKHVTsDQYQ6AEIQjAE#v=onepage&q=is%20the%20affine%20group%20Aff(R%5En)%20amenable%3F&f=false). Note that the affine group $Aff(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is solvable if and only if $n=1$ (which is the group above). For a discrete subgroup $\Gamma$ in $Aff(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are equivalent: $(1)$ $\Gamma$ is amenable, $(2)$ $\Gamma$ is virtually solvable.

Answer (score 1):

It is solvable, thus it is amenable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group#Examples